# c# remove zeros from middle of string

Tags: c#, string, c#-4.0, trim

I'm working an a c#-4.0 Windows Form application and I need to remove padding zeros from a serial number.

My serial is stored in a string and looks something like this **BMS21-14-000000000000000000120**, and the end result I'm after is **BMS21-14-120**.

The serial number structure is:

- **BMS21** is the prefix.
- **14** is the production year.
- **120** is an incrementing number.

Now, the length on our prefix and incrementing numbers will change from product to product, but the structure is consistent. It's always *prefix*, *year* and *incrementing#* and they are always separated by a dash.

I tried following the example outlined by [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8d7z2kk(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2) but I couldn't get it to work for our serial numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a one-liner for you:

```
var serial = "BMS21-14-000000000000000000120";
serial = Regex.Replace(serial, @"(?<=-\d+-)0+", String.Empty);
```

Here's an explanation:

- `0+` will match a series of zeros.
- `(?<=-\d+-)` is a *positive lookbehind* (`(?<=`...`)`). It will assert that what precedes the zeros is a dash, followed by a series of digits (`\d+`), and another dash. Being an assertion, it won't match anything by itself. `\d+` could have been replaced by `\d{2}` if you wanted to ensure the production year part is made of exactly two digits.

As a side note, you could add `(?=\d)` after `0+`. It's a *positive lookahead* that would ensure there's at least one digit left. This would let you reduce `BMS21-14-000000000000000000000` to `BMS21-14-0` instead of `BMS21-14-`.

Comment: your regex is a good option. Could you explain the pattern please?

Comment: @Marco Sure, I added some explanation.

Comment: I did not know about assertions, but actually they are really needed. Thanks! +1.

Comment: @Marco Here's an alternative without lookbehinds: `Regex.Replace(serial, @"(-\d+-)0+", "$1");` Simply match everything but keep the year part in the replacement string.

Comment: Thank you, this is perfectly simple solution. And thank you very much for the explanation! As a self-taught programmer learning on the job, answers like this are simply the best!

Comment: Very interesting! Although I will own up to being somewhat allergic to regular expressions. I know that some people can do magical things with them, but my wizard's cap is bent and my brain tries to crawl out of my head when I try to force it to understand Regex. Darned brain.

Comment: @Cyberherbalist You could read [this](http://regex.info/book.html) and do your brain a favor... Perhaps even become a regex wizard yourself ;)

Comment: Yes, well, I've considered getting that book several times. I'd almost rather pluck out all my nose hairs one by one.  Hah.  OK, you've convinced me.  Just ordered it via Amazon Prime.  If it makes my brain explode I will blame you! :-)

Comment: @Cyberherbalist I've actually laughed :) Anyway don't worry, it's very well explained and a great material, I'm sure you won't regret your purchase.

Answer (score 5):

Here's an alternate solution:

```
static string FormatSerialNumber(string serialNumber)
{
    var parts = serialNumber.Split('-');
    parts[2] = parts[2].TrimStart('0');
    return string.Join("-", parts);
}

// Call it like this:
FormatSerialNumber("BMS21-14-000000000000000000120") // BMS21-14-120
```

You may also want to add code to validate the input to this function if your serial number string might not strictly conform to this format.

Answer (score 3):

I'm glad to see that you found an answer yourself. However, maybe this is shorter:

```
var parts="BMS21-14-000000000000000000120".Split('-');
var result = string.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}", parts[0], parts[1], int.Parse(parts[2]));
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Comment: It's important to note that this would only work if the last part of the string is less than `int.MaxValue` (2147483647). `long.Parse` would get you closer to the maximum value suggested by the serial number format, but would would break at `long.MaxValue` (9223372036854775807)

Comment: @p.s.w.g: Valid point. In that case I need a solution like yours. +1 for you.

Answer (score 2):

```
string serial = "BMS21 - 14 - 000000000000000000120";

string[] splitSerial = serial.Split('-');

int code = Convert.ToInt32(splitSerial[2]);

serial = splitSerial[0] + '-' + splitSerial[1] + '-' + code.ToString();
```

Comment: This is IMHO the best answer

Answer (score 1):

An extension method:

```
public static string RemoveZeros(this string sn)
{
    int ndx = sn.IndexOf('-');
    ndx = sn.IndexOf('-', ndx + 1);
    int cnt = ndx + 1;
    while (sn[cnt] == '0')
    {           
        cnt++;
    }
    return sn.Remove(ndx + 1, cnt - ndx - 1);
}
```

Use it like this:

```
string serial = "BMS21-14-000000000000000000120".RemoveZeros();
```

Comment: Yes, but I'm pretty sure extension methods like this are a little bit overkill, since it will be applied to all strings, not just the target ones.  Just thinking that might be worth mentioning, too.

Comment: @Cyberherbalist, extension methods is only syntactic sugar for better code readability(sometimes). They will not be "applied to all strings". They are just instruction for IDE to "show this static method as public method of class X"(in code that has extension method namespaces using), and instruction for compiler to correctly resolve calls to them. In compiled code they are just static methods. Also you could just remove "this" keyword from arguments, and use this piece of code just as normal static method, which he is anyways.

Comment: In this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/644201/how-do-i-add-a-method-to-a-property I got a similar answer, but many of the answerers had cautions to give about extension methods, @rufanov. It seemed they had a reason for the caution -- perhaps they didn't?

Comment: @Cyberherbalist - The commenter on your answer is wrong. Extension methods only apply on strings that you want it too. It does NOT affect all strings.

Comment: @Cyberherbalist, they didn't. Extension methods are just IDE and compiler feature. In compiled code, they are become just normal static methods. They only change what you see in IDE auto-complete feature when you typed "someClassObject." and added "using NamespaceWhereExtentionMethodsDefined" to your code file(or only in current class if extension method declared as private). In exchange of showing in your auto-complete for some class, they can give your code better readability.

Comment: @Cyberherbalist, but yes, there can be some cons.. Sometimes people overuse them, by "doing everything using standard framework classes and extension methods", even where using of class inheritance can result in much more clean and maintainable code.

Comment: @rufanov Thanks to you, also!  I can see how this could be overused.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured this out thanks to [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732808/find-index-of-number-from-a-string-in-c-sharp).

Here is my code that works:

```
            for (int i = 0; i < _dtSerial.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                DataRow dr = _dtSerial.Rows[i];
                string fullSer = _dtSerial.Rows[i].Field<string>("ser_num");

                //Get index for the begining of the string that needs replacing
                int foundS1 = fullSer.IndexOf("-00");

                //Get index of the first non-zero value in my string
                int foundS2 = fullSer.IndexOfAny("123456789".ToArray(), foundS1 + 1);
                if (foundS1 != foundS2 && foundS1 >= 0)
                {
                    fullSer = fullSer.Remove(foundS1 + 1, (foundS2 - foundS1) - 1);
                }
                dr["Serial"] = fullSer;
            }
```

Getting the index for the beginning of the padded zeros was easy because they will always begin with **-00**, but my issue was getting the index of the first non-zero value towards the end of the serial number string.

But then I figured out how to use `.IndexOfAny()` and it worked like a charm.

Comment: OK, but it's unnecessarily complex, IMHO. It's also a lot less straitforward than p.s.w.g.'s answer.  Just sayin'

Comment: Agreed, very glad I decided to post this even though I thought I had it figured out. So many good answers, learned a lot today!

Comment: And the more you use SO the more you will learn! Hope to see you around the place as time goes on.